# Popup NSColorPanel?

Tags: cocoa, nscolor

Is it possible to make an NSColorPanel 'Pop Up', almost like a popup menu, from the NSColorWell?

I don't like how it's implemented as a palette, as it's sometimes not  obvious which NSColorWell it's associated with.

Thanks!

MT

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd need to create your own color inspector and color well. To get it to pop up above your existing control, you'd need to create a child window and attach it to your existing window. The color palette controls would go in the child window.

However, I'd recommend you avoid doing this. The existing color palette mechanism is time-tested and works across multiple applications.